# Distance between two sets, understanding least upper bound property and applications of it

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

If $A, B ⊂ R^m$ are nonempty sets, then the distance between A and B is defined as
${\rm dist}(A, B)=\inf{|p − q| : p ∈ A , q ∈ B}$

While ${\rm dist}(A, B)$ may not be achieved as the minimum of $|p − q|$ for an actual pair of points in the sets $A$ and $B$, the fact that $\inf S$ is always a number in the closure of $S$ implies that there must exist two sequences of points, $\{p_n\}\subset A$ and $\{q_n\} \subset B$, such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} |p_n − q_n| = {\rm dist}(A, B)$. However, neither $\{p_n\}$ nor $\{q_n\}$ itself need be a convergent sequence.

How come it doesn't need to be a convergent sequence?
I couldn't understand that part.

And $\inf S$ is defined as the maximum element of the set of lower bounds for $S$ right? And my question is :
Would this $\inf S$ always be a member of $S$ closure?, 
Is it also the limit of some sequence in $S$?,

Thanks.

Comment: Here's an example.  Let $p_n = {n + 1/n}; \lim p_n = \infty$.  Let $q_n = {n + 2/n}; \lim q_n = \infty$.  Bout $\lim |p_n - q_n| = \lim 1/n = 0$.

Comment: $\inf S$ is always in the closure because for each $n\geq 1$, you can find $s_n \in S$ such that $s_n<\inf S +1/n$.

Comment: @fleablood I think you meant $q_n = n$.

Comment: Keep in mind the difference between max (or min) and sup (or inf) is that max is the largest element *IN* the set.  There need not be any such element.  (example min{1/n} does not exist.) Sup simply need to be the least upper bound, which *does* exist if the set is bounded.  (example inf{1/n} = 0).  If the max (or min) exists, then sup (or inf) is equal to the max (or min) but the max/min need not exist.

Comment: @hubble actually I didn't.  But I should have maybe.

Comment: Nother example $A = \{(p,q)|p^2 + q^2 = 2; p \in \mathbb Q\}$ and $B = \{(\sqrt{2},0)\}$.  A is circle with radius $\sqrt{2}$ but with all the irrational x values removed.  B is simply a point that would be on the circle except it has been removed.  There is no min distance between to point in B and the set A as we can get as close to b as we like.  *BUT* we can never get a distance that actually *is* zero.  So dist = inf (d()) = 0, even though there is no actual d() = 0.

Comment: Would inf be in the closure?  Yes.  inf is a limit point.  limit points need not be in the set but the must be in the closure of the set as that is the definition of what a closed set (or the closure of the set) is.

Comment: Yeah... that's the kicker.  For a bounded set.  inf is a limit point of the set.  If the set isn't closed inf need not be in the set.  If inf is not in the set then there is no min because for any element in the set there'd be a point in the set between it and inf.  If inf is in the set then it is the min (because nothing can be smaller).  If the set is closed then inf is in the set as it is a limit point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\renewcommand\dist{\operatorname{dist}}$In general, we may consider the set $D = \{|p - q| : p \in A, q \in B\}$, which is bounded below by $0$. Then $\dist(A,B) = \inf D$, so there is a sequence in $D$ that converges to $\dist(A,B)$; this is equivalent to there being sequences $p_n \in A$ and $q_n \in B$ such that $|p_n - q_n| \to \dist(A,B)$.

But it may not be the case that $\inf D \in D$, even when both sets are closed. If $\inf D \notin D$, and $A$ and $B$ are closed, then given two convergent sequences $p_n$ in $A$ and $q_n$ in $B$, then $\lim p_n \in A$ and $\lim q_n \in B$ because both sets are closed, but $\lim |p_n - q_n| = |\lim p_n - \lim q_n| > \dist(A,B)$ (because $|\lim p_n - \lim q_n| \in D$).

For example, consider these two closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$: $A = \{(x,y) : y \le 0\}$ and $B = \{(x,y) : y \ge e^{-x}\}$. (At this point I suggest drawing these two sets.) Then $D = (0,\infty)$ so $\dist(A,B) = 0$. The two sets are disjoint, so there are no convergent sequences $p_n \in A$ and $q_n \in B$ such that $\lim |p_n - q_n| = |\lim p_n - \lim q_n| = 0$ (for otherwise $\lim p_n = \lim q_n \in A \cap B = \varnothing$). But we can consider the sequences of points $p_n = (n,0) \in A$ and $q_n = (n,e^{-n}) \in B$. The two sequences obviously don't converge, but $|p_n - q_n| = e^{-n} \to 0$. Thus $\dist(A,B) = 0$.

Note: If $A$ is closed and $B$ is *compact*, then it can be shown that there are points $p \in A$ and $q \in B$ with $|p - q| = \dist(A,B)$. (Proof sketch: Because $B$ is compact there is $q \in B$ with $\dist(A,q) = \dist(A,B)$. Then there is a sequence $p_n \in A$ with $|p_n - q| \le \dist(A,B) + 1/n$. The sequence is contained in the closed and bounded (hence compact) set $\{a : |a-q| \le \dist(A,B)+1\} \cap A$, so it has a convergent subsequence whose limit $p$ satisfies $|p - q| = \dist(A,B)$.)