# Prove that there is a non-zero distance between any point outside an open set and any point in a closed-bounded subset (Complex Analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis

Question: If $S \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is open and $L \subset S$ is closed and bounded, show that there exists a $\delta$ such that $|z-w|>\delta$ for all $z \in L$ and $w \notin S$

Attempt: I am considering the set $P := K^C \cap S$ which is open as $K^C$ is, so for every element $a$ of $P$, we can find an $r>0$ such that this is the radius of an open ball centered at $a$ contained in $P$.  I now want to set $\delta$ to be the minimum of all such $r$ such that $r$ is the maximum for a particular point $a$. However, I am not sure how to show that this set even has a minimum element, and I feel that this probably isn't even the case. I can imagine a set in which $P$ kind of bottlenecks and the set of all $r$ wouldn't have a minimum, but an infimum of $0$.

Comment: this may be of interest: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1952518

Comment: Since $L$ and $S^c$ are disjoint closed sets, the above is implied by the Hausdorff distance being a valid distance i.e. that $d_H(L,S^c) > 0$. I will search for a duplicate in this regard. Look up proof of "Hausdorff distance is a distance"